# Is there a global way to update location for all location based apps?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, geolocation, gps, mobile-phones

I have a WP7 phone and noticed, while being indoor, some location based apps can't determine my location.

If I have 10 location based apps, I am not going to launch them all just before I enter a building and update my location. I was wondering what solutions mobile apps developers do to solve this issue? Does the phone save its location on an ongoing basis into local storage which mobile apps can use if the GPS signal is not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Location services maintain positional information that applicatons can consume. Typically, when indoors the accuracy of the current position is low, but the location services usually maintain a position. The reason that some apps can't determine your location would be down to the way they are implemented. Obviously, I can't give you a conclusive answer, but some may take the current location from the location services and mask the accuracy from you as a user, whereas others might wait for a new position from the location services, which could take a while.

The approach depends on the application and how/why the location is used, but personally I'd take the current position and let the user see the accuracy in some form or other, and then update that position as they come in from the location services rather than waiting for a new position before displaying anything.